# PgAdmin for Windows in the latest version (4.28) doesn't start anymore, hangs in the loading screen and shows JavaScript errors in the browser console

Tags: javascript, windows, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

[PgAdmin in the latest version (4.28)](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v4.28/windows/) doesn't start anymore, hangs in the loading screen and shows JavaScript errors in the browser console. What can I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is simple although I don't really know why it occurs from that version on:

1. Open the registry editor (Search for regedit.exe)
2. Run it as administrator
3. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js`
4. Adjust `Content Type` from `text/plain` to `text/javascript`
5. Restart pgAdmin and it should work again.
6. Maybe, you will have to clean your browser cache or restart your computer as well (Thanks to the Kassym and Bruce).

As already I said, I have no idea why or how this happens, maybe someone from the team can add this as a comment here and I will update my answer.

Comment: I had to clear my browser cache/delete history, but eventually got it working.

Comment: I had to restart my computer after this, but it did work after that. Thanks.

Comment: I will update the answer, thank you for yout experiences.

Comment: Didn't need to restart the computer, but I did need to restart the pgAdmin server ("Shut down server" from the tray icon).